# I'm trying to find a value from one range in another. If exist replace except blanks, if not exist create new line

Tags: vba, excel, find

I'm trying to find a value from one range in another.
If exist replace except blanks, if not exist create new line

I have two files 'SourceFile' and 'TargetFile'.
'TargetFile' is where I store my information.
'SourceFile' is an updated file with new information.

This code right now does the following.
Finds a value in TargetFile, goes to SourceFile and updates column B and C.
If the value is not found, copies from SourceFile to TargetFile columns A, B and C.

But what I need is that if the SourceFile contains blanks in column B or C and if the TargetFile already contains information.
Basically I want to keep the previous information when we have a blank in the SourceFile.

Do you have any idea how to modify this current code to make it funtional?

```
Sub Test2()

Dim i As Integer
k = Workbooks("SourceFile.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To k
l = 1

    findvalue = Workbooks("SourceFile.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value

    With Workbooks("TargetFile.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1")
        l = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Set j = .Range("A:A").Find(findvalue)

        If Not j Is Nothing Then
            .Cells(j.Row, j.Column).Offset(0, 1).Value = Workbooks("SourceFile.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value
            .Cells(j.Row, j.Column).Offset(0, 2).Value = Workbooks("SourceFile.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3).Value
        Else
            .Cells(l, 1).Value = Workbooks("SourceFile.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value
            .Cells(l, 2).Value = Workbooks("SourceFile.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value
            .Cells(l, 3).Value = Workbooks("SourceFile.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3).Value
        End If

    End With

Next i
End Sub
```

Thanks for your help,
Luis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a check around the update statements for B and C.  Only update if the values in the SourceFile are not blank.

```
    If Not j Is Nothing Then
        If Workbooks("SourceFile.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value <> "" Then
            .Cells(j.Row, j.Column).Offset(0, 1).Value = Workbooks("SourceFile.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value
            .Cells(j.Row, j.Column).Offset(0, 2).Value = Workbooks("SourceFile.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3).Value
        End if
    Else
        .Cells(l, 1).Value = Workbooks("SourceFile.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value
        .Cells(l, 2).Value = Workbooks("SourceFile.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value
        .Cells(l, 3).Value = Workbooks("SourceFile.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3).Value
    End If
```

if you want one or the other if it exists in the sourcefile, put the check around each one.

```
    If Not j Is Nothing Then
        If Workbooks("SourceFile.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value <> "" Then
            .Cells(j.Row, j.Column).Offset(0, 1).Value = Workbooks("SourceFile.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value
        End if
        If Workbooks("SourceFile.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3).Value <> "" Then
            .Cells(j.Row, j.Column).Offset(0, 2).Value = Workbooks("SourceFile.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3).Value
        End if
    Else
        .Cells(l, 1).Value = Workbooks("SourceFile.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value
        .Cells(l, 2).Value = Workbooks("SourceFile.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value
        .Cells(l, 3).Value = Workbooks("SourceFile.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3).Value
    End If
```